# Make windows 7 forget network drive paths

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I once connected my network drives using the GUI and had selected the "Remember" feature. So every time the computer reboots, it auto-connects to the network drives.

Is there a way to tell it not to auto-reconnect these drives anymore?

I've tried removing the drives, then re-adding them without the "Remember" feature, but no-go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open a command prompt, and type

```
net use X: /delete
```

where **X:** is the drive letter of the mapped drive. If you want to see all of the connections available for deletion, just do

```
net use
```

Comment: You can use `net use * /d /y` to quickly stop all connections, with or without drive letters.

Comment: @grawity I'd post that as a separate answer if I were you.  I almost did, myself.

Answer (score 1):

While I prefer the cli method listed above, it is worth mentioning another way is to right click "Computer" and click "Disconnect Network Drive". Any drives still in use will be listed, can be highlighted and disconnected through the resulting window.

Comment: I couldn't remember if that permanently removes the drive mapping, and I'm not where I can test it. Does it?

Comment: Yes it's permanent. Unless one of the drives is part of a domain group policy or a log on script.